# C# Use instance of a class made in Form 1 in Form 2

Tags: c#, .net, class, constructor, reference

I want to Use an instance of a class made in Form 1 in Form 2 (i changed it to a list for simplicity of example code:

Not only that, I want Form 2 to be able to modify it (Clear it at some point).
The advice I got was this, although I was not told how due to "no spoonfeeding allowed"

```
namespace automationControls.FileTime
{
    public class Form_Main : Form
    {
        public List<string> folderList; //<---- i want to access this.....

        private void button_showForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form_Log ConfirmBoxForm = new Form_Log(this);
            ConfirmBoxForm.Show();
        }
}

//form_Main opens form_Log


namespace automationControls.FileTime
{
    public partial class Form_Log : Form
    {
        public Form_Log(Form_Main _f1)
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            How.Do.I.AccessForm_Main.folderList.Clear();//<---- ............. in this function
        }
     }
}
```

Answered:In the constructor of Form_Log, store the reference to _f1 somewhere you can access it from elsewhere in Form_Log

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. Selman22's solution seems right but that can't possibly be your problem, since it would be too obvious?

Comment: @AndreasMüller Selman22 solved it. However I had another problem that I did not know about and was preventing me from realizing it (my FormClosing function became somehow unlinked and useless-i presume through many edit undo's) Also, Don't assume, I am new to C#, once Selman2 posted his answer(what I had tried previously and edited out thinking it was wrong) I looked elsewhere for mistakes.

Comment: alright. Good that you got it fixed then. Make sure to mark his answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the constructor that you have already added your form?

```
private Form_Main _mainForm;
public Form_Log(Form_Main _f1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _mainForm = _f1;
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var myList = _mainForm.folderList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
public class Form_Main : Form
{
    public List<string> folderList; //<---- i want to access this.....

    private void button_showForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form_Log ConfirmBoxForm = new Form_Log(this);
        ConfirmBoxForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Form log :

```
public partial class Form_Log : Form
{
    private Form_Main _mainForm;
    public Form_Log(Form_Main _f1)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       _mainForm = _f1;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
      _mainForm.folderList.Clear();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how advanced is your project but in this situation i would use delegates. Here is how i would do it:

```
public delegate void ModifyCollectionHandler(string parameter);
public delegate void ClearCollectionHandler();
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<string> folderList;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2()
        form.ClearItem+=form_ClearItem;
        form.AddItem+=form_AddItem;
        form.DeleteItem+=form_DeleteItem;
    }

    void form_DeleteItem(string parameter)
    {
        if (folderList == null)
            return;
        folderList.Remove(parameter);
    }

    void form_AddItem(string parameter)
    {
        if (folderList == null)
            folderList = new List<string>();
        folderList.Add(parameter);
    }

    void form_ClearItem()
    {
        if (folderList != null)
            folderList.Clear();
    }
}
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event ModifyCollectionHandler AddItem;
    public event ModifyCollectionHandler DeleteItem;
    public event ClearCollectionHandler ClearItem;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ClearItem != null)
            ClearItem();
    }
}
```

I hope I helped you :)
Best regards

Answer (score -2):

in the Form1 put this :

```
public static List<string> folderList;
```

you can simply call it from any form ex:Form2 like this :

```
From1.folderList.Clear();
```